# how to overwrite inline styles in print css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, overriding

i know, inline styles are "evil", but there are inserted in html with javascript (jQuery animation). so, is it possible?

Comment: Does printing a webpage render the JS? Sorry, not much help just a question - wouldn't have thought it did...

Comment: i thing not, but when the page loads, the js will be executed and the styles added. so when i print the page, these styles still been in the dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting !important between the value and the semi-colon in your print stylesheet:

```
body {
    background-color: #0f0 !important;
}
```

Comment: indeed it does, however to override the style in some browsers you need to use the attr selector, which ie6 does not support

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
  <div style="background: red;">
        The inline styles for this div should make it red.
    </div>
```

Can be overridden with:

```
div[style] {
   background: yellow !important;
}
```

You can add `!important` to any css property

Comment: I thought inline styles could not be overidden, even by !important?

Comment: The combination of the attr selector and the !important is key.